# How to map common fields inside a hibernate POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, postgresql-9.4

I have some common fields in every table, so that I want one hibernate POJO and extends from it:

```
public class BaseClass {
   @Column(name="isActive")
   private Boolean isActive;

   public BaseClass() {
      isActive = true;
   }
   // Getter and Setter
}

....
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABC", schema = "ABC")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ABC_seq", sequenceName = "ABC_seq", schema = "ABC", allocationSize = 1)
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  @Id
  // Other stuff here
  public SubClass() {
    super();
  }
}
```

SubClass works so far, but changes of isActives setter doesn't have any effect to my database (Postgres).
Marking BaseClass as @Entity doesn't have any effect either.
My solutions looks like the other one here on SO.

Comment: The base class must be annotated with MappedSuperclass.

Comment: HIbernate provides you with 3 strategies which you can implement to map  a subclass with superclass, have a look here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: @JB Nizet
Thank you, it works for me. I thought while reading some google search results, that MappedSuperclass is only for Class with an id (primary key). Shame on me :/